# How can I set up and use cron jobs in Magento 1.7 on Mac?

Tags: cron

Is there a built-in cron job functionality in Magento and what is the suggested way to use cron job (in particular for updating stock quantities of products, but this is not important here in this question)? We have a .CSV that is periodically updated and we want the cron job to take it periodically and process it, so we want to use cron and not any other way. Cron job is way we want to go, but I want to know more about cron job integration in Magento. What is the best way to do this? I added the Magento cron using this:

```
crontab -e
```

and added this line there:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/sh /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/mymagento/cron.sh
```

I also created the cron using a module, like this:

```
<config>
    ...
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <mynamespace_mymodule_test>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>mymodule/observer::test</model></run>
            </mynamespace_mymodule_test>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
    ...
</config>
```

I created the observer (in Mynamespace/Mymodule/Model/Observer.php) and its method like this:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer {

    public function test(){
        error_log("success!!!!!");
    }
}
```

So I expect to get that message logged, but it is not. It's never logged. I can see the cron in the cron_schedule table if I run [mymagento]/cron.php in the browser, but the message is not logged. What am I missing here?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: I am using mac OS Sierra 10.12.1, but I also need to know how to do this on a Linux.

Comment: Ok I will answer for the linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using own linux system then fire this command in your terminal

`crontab -e`

After that you will see the in that file add below command

`*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /[magento_path]/cron.sh` and save may be using `ctrl+x`

For your php script you can add via below command

`*/5 * * * * php -f /[magento_path]/YourPHPScriptPath/yourscriptname.php`

If you are doing in host then most of the host has `cronjob` setup wizards from there you can setup the cronjob

**OR**

You can create a module and within that you can use magento cron functionality

You can find tutorial at here.

If you create module then you can see entry in `cron_schedule` tabel

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202463/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-magento-module

http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/

Be sure you added `cron.sh` file in your cronjob otherwise your and any magento cron will not trigger.

Comment: And where is my cron job and how to set it run for example an PHP script?

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic You have created php script for cron job ?  let me update my answer

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic instead of 5 put 15 over there and it will work

Comment: I am in my {magento} root directory and I did crontab -e, and I added the line */5 * * * * php -f /cron_test.php because my cron_test.php is also in {magento} root directory. And now I am not seeing my cron_test.php in the cron_schedule table. What am I missing?

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic For your custom php script you wont see any entry in cron_schedule table

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic for your custom php script you can write some value in some custom file  and debug that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49594/discussion-between-vladimir-despotovic-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: I tried setting the cron in a module and still it didn't work.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic can you  provide detail code ??

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Murtuza I figured out to replace the sh line in crontab with this one:

```
*/1 * * * * /Applications/XAMPP/bin/php /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/mymagento/cron.php
```

I also fixed a typo with my module's model. After that, the cron works fine and the method is called periodicaly.

Comment: for your custom script you can try this code to.         `*/1 * * * * /Applications/XAMPP/bin/php     /[magento_path]/YourPHPScriptPath/yourscriptname.php`